# SUM and Group By Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, sum

I use this query:

```
 SELECT 
     logdate, 
     SUM(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as traffic, 
     customer 
 FROM 
     `Logdata` 
 WHERE 
     customer is not null AND 
     logdate >= "2016-07-01" AND 
     logdate <= "2016-07-30" 
 GROUP By logdate, customer
```

on this table with currently around 6 mio rows (but there will be 10 times more rows):

```
CREATE TABLE `Logdata` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `logdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `logtime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `method` smallint(6) DEFAULT '200',
  `region` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

with this keys:

```
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_logdate` (`logdate`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_method` (`method`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_customer` (`customer`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_customer_logdate` (`logdate`,`customer`);
```

and this execution plan:

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra
1 | SIMPLE | Logdata | NULL | index | IDX_logdate,IDX_customer,idx_customer_logdate | idx_customer_logdate | 391 | NULL | 6247535 | 25.00 | Using where
```

InnoDB Config is:

```
InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.0G/1.1G
InnoDB buffer pool instances: 2
```

With ~6mio rows in the table the query takes 14 seconds. Which will get worse as the amount of rows is increasing in a very fast pace.

The questions:

- Would i benefit in this case from the myisam table engine?
- What could i do to further optimize the query or the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would i benefit in this case from the myisam table engine?

No you won't.

> What could i do to further optimize the query or the settings?

Materialize the query.

MySQL does not have built-in means to do that easily (similar to indexed views in SQL Server or materialized views in Oracle) so you'll have to put some effort into it.

Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log_customer_date
        (
        customer BIGINT NOT NULL,
        logdate DATE NOT NULL,
        sumbytes BIGINT NOT NULL,
        countrecords BIGINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (customer, logdate)
        )
```

fill it:

```
INSERT
INTO    log_customer_date
SELECT  customer, logdate, SUM(bytes) sumbytes, COUNT(*) countrecords
FROM    logdata
GROUP BY
        customer, logdate
```

and add further records in a trigger:

```
INSERT
INTO    log_customer_date
VALUES  (NEW.customer, NEW.logdate, NEW.bytes, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  sumbytes = sumbytes + VALUES(sumbytes),
        countrecords = countrecords + VALUES(countrecords)
```

or in a script every once in a while:

```
INSERT
INTO    log_customer_date
SELECT  customer, logdate, SUM(bytes) sumbytes, COUNT(*) countrecords
FROM    logdata
WHERE   id > :lastid
GROUP BY
        customer, logdate
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  sumbytes = sumbytes + VALUES(sumbytes),
        countrecords = countrecords + VALUES(countrecords)
```

, recording the highest `id` by the moment of the insert somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are I/O-bound.  That *cannot* be solved by tuning!

- Normalize `region`, `customer`, etc.  This will save a lot of space and shrink the data, thereby making queries faster.
- Consider not splitting `date` and `time` -- it is usually less complex in the long run to have a single `DATETIME`.
- As @Quassnoi spells out, summarize the day's data each night.  Put the results into a [*summary table*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/).  Then fetch from that table.  This will speed things up a *lot*.
- In composite indexes, put the '=' column first, the 'range' column last: `INDEX(customer, logdate)`.